# Redirect customers to Home page/previous page after login/create account in magento 2 instead of Dashboard?

Tags: magento2, redirect, dashboard

I am trying to redirect to user after login or creating account to either home page or previous page. My controller code is following it is not able to login or create an account.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace PinkBlue\Redirect\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Redirect extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /** @var Registration */
    protected $registration;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param Registration $registration
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Registration $registration
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->registration = $registration;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Customer register form page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->registration->isAllowed()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //$currentUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface')->getCurrentUrl();
        $catalogSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $previousUrl = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();
        $catalogSession->setCustomerRedirectUrl($previousUrl);


        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give this extension a try https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-redirect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the redirect.

> 1. On the Admin sidebar, tap **Stores**. Then under **Settings**, choose **Configuration**.
> 2. In the panel on the left, under **Customers**, choose **Customer Configuration**.
> 3. Expand the **Login Options** section.
> 4. Set **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging** in to one of the following:
>
>    - **Yes** - The account dashboard appears when customers log in to their accounts.
>    - **No** - Customers can continue shopping after logging in to their accounts.
> 5. When complete, tap **Save Config**.
> 6. Click the **Cache Management** link in the yellow modal that shows up.
>
> [image]
>
> 7. Select the **Configuration** and **Page Cache** checkboxes.
>
> [image]
>
> 8. Click **Submit** to refresh the two selected cache types.
>
> [image]

[Magento Docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ce/user_guide/customers/login-landing-page.html?Highlight=login%20redirect) are your friend.

Cheers!

Comment: I have  already tried to do the same but it was not working in my system I tried in other system it worked but behaving different sometime again tried after clearing system history  its working fine Now!! Thanks!!

Comment: After Login it is redirecting to home page but that is not logged In, again when I click to Sign In /Create it is redirecting to Dashboard. :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you said "but that is not logged in".  Did you clear the cache afterwards? I'll update my answer to reflect having to clear the cache.

Comment: I mean ''but that is not logged In" this that is not showing User name in header still having Sign In /Create option for logged In  user. is there any session issue?

Comment: I updated my answer to include refreshing the cache. Are you still having issues after completing those steps? If so, then there is something else going on. Start by looking at the log files in the `var/log` directory. And if you possibly have another module that you were developing still enabled, don't forget to disable/remove it.

Comment: Will it not work for Social Logged in customer?

Comment: I would contact the developer of the extension you are referring to directly and ask them if it's compatible or if they are aware of the possible misbehavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply below solution.

In your custom theme phtml file , for login link, add below code.

```
$currentUrl  = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
$login_url = $this->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => base64_encode($currentUrl)));
```

May this will help you.

Thank you

Comment: yes this is working , but when we can search product list of any category and then click on login button then it give 404 error i think it not get paramters from url. Give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use in controller:

```
return $this->_redirect($previousUrl);
```

Also check the value in $previousUrl, it could be blank.

In order your login could work correctly with the full page cache - do not forget  to flush the customer data in the browser local storage after registration or login.

We use the same logic in  our Twitter & Facebook Login Free extension  for Magento.

Hope it will help you.